# Python: error when trying to write or overwrite a text file in a directory

Tags: python, windows, file

I have written a python script made up of two functions:

note() : to write a text file in a directory named target_dir.

file_exist(): that checks whether a text file starting with a string 'note' is already existing in the target_dir. If this is the case I would like to overwrite the text file by running again note() function. Here is the code:

```
import glob, os, shutil, time


def note():
    """ Write the info a in a txt file"""
    print 'Please enter few info:\n '
    a = raw_input('Aim: ')     
    add = raw_input('Additional info: ')
    file_name = 'note_' + time.strftime('%d%m%Y') + '.txt'    #which is: note_23112015.txt
    myfile = open(file_name, 'w')
    myfile.write('Aim: '+ a +'\n')      
    myfile.write('Additional info: '+ add +'\n')
    myfile.close()
    shutil.copy2(file_name, target_dir)


def file_exist():
    """Check if a file starting with the string 'note' already exist."""
    txt = [i for i in os.listdir(target_dir) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(target_dir,i)) and 'note' in i]
    if txt:
        inp = raw_input('Text File already exist, do you want overwrite?(y or n)')
        if inp == 'y':
            note()
    else:
        note()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Change the directory path    
    target_dir = 'C:/Users/data' # target directory
    file_exist()
```

When I try to run the script the text file is generated correctly but I also get a bunch of errors ending with:

```
Error: note_23112015.txt and `C:/Users/data\note_23112015.txt` are the same file
```

Somebody knows what is wrong with this code?
Thank you

Comment: What line is the error happening on? If your bunch of errors is actually a stack trace, it should tell you there.

Comment: The code is working fine for me with no errors.

Comment: Maybe, you are in your target directory.

Comment: Yes I am! and now that you tell me I try not to be in the target directory and it works fine!! Why it does not work if I run the script from the target directory? How can I fix that? thanks a lot

Comment: `shutil.copy2(file_name, target_dir)` copies from the current directory to the target directory. if the current and target are the same, it'll fail. You could do `os.path.normpath(os.path.basename(target_dir)) == os.getcwd()` and skip the copy.

Comment: @tdelaney using os.path.normpath(os.path.basename(target_dir)) == os.getcwd() in place of copy2 works fine, could you please explain me your code?

Answer (score 0):

In the line `shutil.copy2(file_name, target_dir)`, you are copying the file to the path it's already in. You need either

1) to change the target directory or the searching directory (currently being drawn from your working directory) so that they don't match each other

or

2) to change the name of the output file.

However, upon re-reading your description, it sounds like you can just drop the copy2 line entirely. Do you need two copies of the updated files?

EDIT:

Per OP's request, I'll code my words:

<s>`shutil.copy2(file_name, target_dir)`</s>

Comment: I would need only to write the text file in my target directory independently from where I run the script, could you please code your words? thanks

Comment: @diegus, it's still not quite clear what you want. Do you want two copies of the text file? If so, do you want to preserve the original as it was, or do you want two copies of the updated text file? Are the original text files already in the target directory? Your source and target directories are the same; do you want/need that to be the case?